# Form não retornando os dados Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, table

Estou fazendo um formulário e após salvar o cliente quero listar os clientes. Realizei o codigo porém na tela não está retornando os dados mas está aparecendo a linha após cadastrar um novo cliente, sendo que no console está vindo o array com os dados.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let head of headElements" scope="col">{{head}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let c of clientes">
        <td>{{c.NOME}}</td>
        <td>{{c.CPF}}</td>
        <td>{{c.EMAIL}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn-primary" (click)="selecionarClientePorId(c.IDCLIENTE)" >Editar</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {


  headElements = ['Nome', 'CPF', 'Email'];
  clientes: any = [];

  url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/clientes';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}


  ngOnInit(){
    return this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((data: any[]) =>{
      this.clientes = data;
      console.log(this.clientes);
    });
}
```

```
export class Cliente {
  constructor(
    public IDCLIENTE: number,
    public NOME: string,
    public CPF: string,
    public EMAIL: string,
    public SENHA: string
  ) {}
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: poderia postar como está vindo o data?

Comment: Adicionei uma foto da tela mostrando o console e a table sem os dados

Answer (score 0):

O problema está no seu template. Repare que os dados que aparecem no console estão minúsculos (cpf, email, etc.) e no seu template estão maiúsculos:

Troque de :

```
<td>{{c.NOME}}</td>
<td>{{c.CPF}}</td>
<td>{{c.EMAIL}}</td>
```

para:

```
<td>{{c.nome}}</td>
<td>{{c.cpf}}</td>
<td>{{c.email}}</td>
```

Comment: @LaisSant'ana para ter certeza do que está chegando no seu template, coloque dentro de algum td o seguinte: `<td>{{c | json}}</td>`. Certifique-se de que as propriedades que serão printadas neste comando são as mesmas utilizadas no seu template. Se puder poste aqui mesmo o conteúdo printado.

Comment: Eu tinha feito alteração no arquivo errado, mas agora testei e foi!! muito obrigada!!

Comment: @LaisSant'ana que legal! precisando é só falar ;)

Answer (score -1):

Verifique o conteúdo do `data` que você está atribuindo a `this.clientes` pode ser que precise utilizar `data.data` para acessar os dados que você quer. Se o problema não estiver na recepção dos dados, na hora de mostrar que está, revise o HTML.

Comment: os dados retornados da API estão printados no console. `data` é um `Array` e não um objeto com a propriedade `data`